# Flexbox column wrap is not equal width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a simple masonry layout using flexbox column wrap, however I've noticed that the column with "Film/TV" and "Pop" is significantly smaller than the others.

How can I force each column to have approximately the same width?

[image]

Here's my CSS code:

```
    & .masonry-layout {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        width: 100%;
        height: 730px;


        & .item {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: var(--theme-border-radius);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            

            & .item__content {
                align-self: flex-end;                
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                color: var(--theme-color-white);
                font-size: calc(var(--teft-typography-base) * 0.75);
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            & .svg {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-grow: 2;
                justify-content: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="masonry-layout">
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/images/landing-page/browse-library/>
        <div class="svg">
            <?php if (!empty ( $item->svg ) ) { echo ( $item->svg ); } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="item__content">
            <span><?php echo esc_html( $item->text ); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not CSS; it's a preprocessor form of CSS. Please post the compiled CSS when asking questions, unless your question is specifically with how to do something in the preprocessed code language (e.g. Sass or Less). Same for the markup -- you have PHP there, not HTML. The compiled HTML (which is the output shown to the visitor) should be included, not pre-compiled PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the span element, everything was sized as expected.

Answer (score 0):

set a minimum width ( or / and ) maximum width to keep them similar or the same size.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code to support your answer?